# How to define client server using socket programming and pass database to client in C#

Tags: c#, sockets, websocket, tcp, tcpclient

I would like to build a socket (TCP) client and server. Here quantity of client can be max two or three machine. Now where the server I will define, it will call main database(hosted) and fetch data to the client when client request to socket server for getting data. Every time when client machine turned on, it will call local socket server for getting data from database. Everything I will need to do in C#, .Net framework without using any third party library service. So here how to define that infrastructure.

Comment: As it stands, this question may be too broad for stack overflow.  You're basically asking us to write your client and server based on your stated requirements, but as explained in [Breaking down "too broad"/"needs more focus" and trying to understand it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/259857/3744182), questions like that are out of scope for this forum.  Take a look at [ask] and https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ for questions that are likely to get answered here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking for after reading the description, but you can use system.net.sockets to make a client and a server that can connect to each other using TCP.
Hope this helped.

Comment: Yes. I established the connection using TCP listener. Now I want to send data(Database data) from TCP Server To TCP Client

Comment: the easiest way would be to convert the object to bytes.
after that you there's a method in the system.net.sockets namespace that will allow you to send it to the server or from server to client

make a byte array and you can use the json system library to convert the object you want to send with serializetoutf8bytes(object).

after that it's just converting the bytes back into the class object using the json system library again once it arrives on the server.